# jQuery не работает селектор по классу после изменения класса

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, frontend

Выводится список материалов вот такого вида. 
По умолчанию у кнопок класс `btn-add-material`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var material_data = new FormData();

  material_data.append('mode', 'get_plan');
  $.ajax({
    url: '../server/express-order/express-order-route.php',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: material_data,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      var answer_json = JSON.parse(data);

      $('#position-count').html(answer_json.total_positions);

      for (var key in answer_json.material_list) {
        //Изменяем все кнопки если их id есть в плане
        $('[data-id-material=' + key + ']').removeClass("btn-success");
        $('[data-id-material=' + key + ']').removeClass("btn-add-material");
        $('[data-id-material=' + key + ']').addClass("btn-danger");
        $('[data-id-material=' + key + ']').addClass("btn-delete-material");
        $('[data-id-material=' + key + ']').html("<i class='material-icons' style='font-size: 1.8em'>delete_sweep</i>");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/**
Как только список выведен, по элементам пробегается скрипт, который перекрашивает кнопку, если материал уже есть в корзине
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-group-item">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Бетон М100 (В-7,5) П3 до -15</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 text-right">
      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">2670.00 ₽ <small>/м3</small></h4>
      <small class="text-info">Цена на 2018-03-18</small>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <button class="btn-add-material btn btn-success" style="width: 100%;" data-id-material="65748">
         <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 1.8em">add_shopping_cart</i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

После всех этих манипуляций, прекрасно работает скрипт добавления материала в корзину, который обращается к элементу через `$('.btn-add-material')`, но абсолютно не работает селектор `$('.btn-delete-material')`. Проверил алертами - событие даже не срабатывает.
Пожалуйста, подскажите в чем может быть проблема.
Может быть необходимо каким то образом "обновлять" DOM после манипуляций?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `$(document).on("click", ".btn-add-material", function(e) { ... });` `$(document).on("click", ".btn-delete-material", function(e) { ... });`

Comment: а где и как этот селектор используется? вероятно на момент селектирования все отрабатывает корректно и таких элементов просто нет.

Comment: В данном случае я не использую ajax совсем. Вариант, предложенный Igor вроде бы работает, но не совсем корректно. Раз модераторы посчитали этот вопрос дубликатом - как угодно.

Comment: @EgorMeldun это не модераторы, а пользователь с золотой плашкой по тегу)

Comment: Вариант Igor 'а работает, спасибо большое! Косяк был в перекрашивании кнопок.
@yolosora, не так часто тут писал, больше читал, поэтому не знал)

Comment: @EgorMeldun это кстати классическое решение для динамически изменяемого контента, т.к. такие события имеют "всплывающий эффект" их можно ловить на уровне корневого элемента

Comment: @yolosora, спасибо за информацию, буду знать! :)